# Filter MySQL statement based on 2 columns (meta_key and meta_value)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following SQL statement to calculate several fields based on wp_postmeta, wp_post and wp_user tables. What I need is to include only results, where all posts have meta_key='key1' and meta_value >= '1.5'. I tried in the statement below but it's not filtering, still show every record.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT (display_name) AS 'user',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'won' else Null End) AS 'Won',
    SUM(Case When meta_key = 'status' Then meta_value = 'lost' else Null End) AS 'Lost',
    COUNT(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End) AS 'Total',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'odd' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg odd',
    ROUND (AVG(Case When meta_key = 'bet' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Avg bet',
    ROUND (SUM(Case When meta_key = 'balance' Then meta_value else Null End), 2) AS 'Balance'
FROM wp_postmeta pm
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON pm.post_id = p.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON p.post_author = u.ID
WHERE Month(post_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND p.post_status='publish' 
GROUP BY (display_name)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key='key1' AND pm.meta_value >='1.5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
ORDER BY Balance DESC
```

Comment: Hi, I notice something. Is pm.meta_value a string or numeric in your actual design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would join the the post meta table multiple times. This should take advantage of indexes to return the query more quickly as well. You probably want to group by the `u.ID` in case two users have the same `display_name`. Using `$wpdb->posts` and `$wpdb->postmeta` is a good idea in case you change your database prefix, which is a good idea for security.

*Note, this is untested.*

```
SELECT 
    display_name user,
    IFNULL(SUM(won.meta_value),0) won,
    IFNULL(SUM(lost.meta_value),0) lost,
    IFNULL(COUNT(odd.meta_value),0) total,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(odd.meta_value),2),0) avg_odd,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(bet.meta_value),2),0) avg_bet,
    IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(balance.meta_value),2),0) balance
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
JOIN {$wpdb->users} u 
    ON p.post_author = u.ID
JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} odd 
    ON p.ID = odd.post_id AND odd.meta_key = 'odd'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} won 
    ON p.ID = won.post_id AND won.meta_key = 'status' AND won.meta_value = 'won'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} lost 
    ON p.ID = lost.post_id AND lost.meta_key = 'status' AND lost.meta_value = 'lost'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} bet 
    ON p.ID = bet.post_id AND bet.meta_key = 'bet'
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} balance 
    ON p.ID = balance.post_id AND balance.meta_key = 'balance'
WHERE 
    MONTH(p.post_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY u.ID
HAVING SUM(odd.meta_value) >= 1.5
ORDER BY balance DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I can't make the above statement work. I want to use this statement in phpmyadmin to pull a ranking. I get an error saying " Invalid use of group function". Also, meta_key 'key1' is actually meta_key 'odd', not sure if that makes any difference. Thanks

Comment: Now I get - #1054 - Unknown column 'won.status' in 'on clause'.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now but not filtering. I'm trying to exclude any posts that have a meta_key=odd with a meta_value>=1.5 from the query but they are not being excluded.

Comment: that's what `HAVING SUM(odd.meta_value) >= 1.5` should do for you - you might need to `CAST`?

Comment: Unless you mean you don't want anything with `odd.meta_value` less than 1.5 being included in the sums/avgs, in which case you should put it on the `JOIN`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28279/discussion-between-qebas-and-doublesharp)